# How to hint to the user to click on the arrow for slide navigation

Tags: website-design, navigation, affordance

I've been doing user testing to make sure users would know how to navigate between elections on the following schema.

[image]

[image]

The left side has voter information, always visible. The right panel has election related information, that panel would slide right and then another arrow on the left would appear but users don't seem to realize about this navigation. It's an informational website, not a webapp so not sure about adding instructional overlay. Any ideas?

Comment: is the right panel always open in some state? Otherwise, what is beneath it? Sorry, a little unclear. And the left 'voter data' pane is persistent, correct?

Comment: Yes it's always open, you can go to the right and then another arrow on the left it would appear (just updated the post with a second image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try making a clear delineation between the persistent voter data, and the election pane, with the steps clearly outlined.

You can use a pair of buttons, with the number of step or 'pages' so:

- They know how many total steps they have to complete
- They can easily navigate back to make an adjustment
- You can see the time label ('45 days') next to the content pane title, as they are related

I put the steps into the header, but you could try a version where it's pinned to the bottom, although if there's scrolling, the content would go 'under' the bar. I'm not sure what your viewport situation is.

[image]